# Pandas - How to get cumidxmax

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In pandas there is a functions to get index of max value using `idxmax` but I am unable to find a function that gives index of `cummax`.

Create dummy data using below code:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05',
                              '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10',
                              '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14'],
                     'Price': [1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7]})
test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'])
test.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
test['Returns'] = test['Price'].pct_change()
test['Cum_Returns'] = (1 + test['Returns']).cumprod()
test['Previous_Peak'] = test['Cum_Returns'].cummax()
```

I want to get index for `cummax()` as well as the next index of `cummax()` where value for `Previous Peak` changes.

Also if `Previous Peak` value gets equal to last `Previous Peak` value we consider that as change in index. E.g. on 8th the `Cum Returns` is 5 so the `Previous Peak` value would be 5 and the `Previous_Peak_index` would also be 8th instead of third

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+-------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------+
|    Date    | Price |   Returns    | Cum_Returns | Previous_Peak | Previous_Peak_index | Next_PP_index |
+------------+-------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------+
| 01/01/2021 |     1 | nan          | nan         | nan           | nan                 | nan           |
| 02/01/2021 |     1 | 0            | 1           | 1             | 02/01/2021          | 03/01/2021    |
| 03/01/2021 |     5 | 4            | 5           | 5             | 03/01/2021          | 08/01/2021    |
| 04/01/2021 |     3 | -0.4         | 3           | 5             | 03/01/2021          | 08/01/2021    |
| 05/01/2021 |     4 | 0.333333333  | 4           | 5             | 03/01/2021          | 08/01/2021    |
| 06/01/2021 |     3 | -0.25        | 3           | 5             | 03/01/2021          | 08/01/2021    |
| 07/01/2021 |     2 | -0.333333333 | 2           | 5             | 03/01/2021          | 08/01/2021    |
| 08/01/2021 |     5 | 1.5          | 5           | 5             | 08/01/2021          | 09/01/2021    |
| 09/01/2021 |     6 | 0.2          | 6           | 6             | 09/01/2021          | 14/01/2021    |
| 10/01/2021 |     4 | -0.333333333 | 4           | 6             | 09/01/2021          | 14/01/2021    |
| 11/01/2021 |     3 | -0.25        | 3           | 6             | 09/01/2021          | 14/01/2021    |
| 12/01/2021 |     2 | -0.333333333 | 2           | 6             | 09/01/2021          | 14/01/2021    |
| 13/01/2021 |     1 | -0.5         | 1           | 6             | 09/01/2021          | 14/01/2021    |
| 14/01/2021 |     7 | 6            | 7           | 7             | 14/01/2021          | nan           |
+------------+-------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I was unable to find `idxmax` for `cummax` how can achieve expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Behold, here be dragons:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.concat([test.Cum_Returns, test.index.to_series()], axis=1)
    .agg(tuple, axis=1)
    .cummax()
    .to_list(),
    columns=["Previous_Peak", "Previous_Peak_index"],
)
x[x.isna().any(axis=1)] = np.nan
g = (
    x.groupby("Previous_Peak_index")["Previous_Peak_index"]
    .agg(list)
    .str[0]
    .shift(-1)
)
x = x.merge(
    g, left_on="Previous_Peak_index", right_index=True, how="left"
).rename(
    columns={
        "Previous_Peak_index_x": "Previous_Peak_index",
        "Previous_Peak_index_y": "Next_PP_index",
    }
)
test[["Previous_Peak", "Previous_Peak_index", "Next_PP_index"]] = x.values
print(test)
```

Prints:

```
            Price   Returns  Cum_Returns Previous_Peak Previous_Peak_index Next_PP_index
Date                                                                                    
2021-01-01      1       NaN          NaN           NaN                 NaT           NaT
2021-01-02      1  0.000000          1.0           1.0          2021-01-02    2021-01-03
2021-01-03      5  4.000000          5.0           5.0          2021-01-03    2021-01-08
2021-01-04      3 -0.400000          3.0           5.0          2021-01-03    2021-01-08
2021-01-05      4  0.333333          4.0           5.0          2021-01-03    2021-01-08
2021-01-06      3 -0.250000          3.0           5.0          2021-01-03    2021-01-08
2021-01-07      2 -0.333333          2.0           5.0          2021-01-03    2021-01-08
2021-01-08      5  1.500000          5.0           5.0          2021-01-08    2021-01-09
2021-01-09      6  0.200000          6.0           6.0          2021-01-09    2021-01-14
2021-01-10      4 -0.333333          4.0           6.0          2021-01-09    2021-01-14
2021-01-11      3 -0.250000          3.0           6.0          2021-01-09    2021-01-14
2021-01-12      2 -0.333333          2.0           6.0          2021-01-09    2021-01-14
2021-01-13      1 -0.500000          1.0           6.0          2021-01-09    2021-01-14
2021-01-14      7  6.000000          7.0           7.0          2021-01-14           NaT
```

---

`test` used:

```
            Price   Returns  Cum_Returns
Date                                    
2021-01-01      1       NaN          NaN
2021-01-02      1  0.000000          1.0
2021-01-03      5  4.000000          5.0
2021-01-04      3 -0.400000          3.0
2021-01-05      4  0.333333          4.0
2021-01-06      3 -0.250000          3.0
2021-01-07      2 -0.333333          2.0
2021-01-08      5  1.500000          5.0
2021-01-09      6  0.200000          6.0
2021-01-10      4 -0.333333          4.0
2021-01-11      3 -0.250000          3.0
2021-01-12      2 -0.333333          2.0
2021-01-13      1 -0.500000          1.0
2021-01-14      7  6.000000          7.0
```

Comment: The solutions seems to work but can you explain the steps that you took to reach the results?